# VMware: Gracefully powering down a VM using the Terminal command line results in power off instead

Tags: command-line, vmware, vmware-fusion

When attempting to perform a graceful shutdown of a VMware Fusion guest VM on MacOS Big Sur 11.6, using the below command line:

```
vmrun stop "/Users/T/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/MGMT1.vmwarevm" -soft
```

The VM simply powers off, leading to a system recovery dialog on next reboot.  There is very little on the 'net about gracefully shutting down guest VMs via the command line (Terminal) in VMware Fusion.  Surely, someone out there has a verified one-liner or script to gracefully shutdown VMs?

Comment: I believe it is `soft` not `-soft`.

Comment: Ditto on Brian’s comment. Source: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-24F54E24-EFB0-4E94-8A07-2AD791F0E497.html#the-vmrun-general-commands-and-parameters-5

Comment: I had tried that.  With just *soft* nothing happens - the VM simply stays up as if nothing happened.

Comment: Does the guest have VMware Tools installed?  Using `soft` (instead of `-soft`) is correct, and that nothing happens implies that `vmrun` sent a shutdown request to the guest, but VMware Tools then didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no combination of vmrun parameters to shutdown a VM gracefully work, I've decided to go with a workaround:  run a scheduled task inside of the VM itself to shut it down.  On Windows:  *Shutdown.exe /s*

Comment: Interesting, but how do you trigger the scheduled task from the host machine?

Comment: I should have explained a bit more - I trigger the task from inside the VM itself through Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: So basically you shutdown down the machine manually? That is almost the same as going to start menu and pressing the shutdown bottom.

Comment: The task is triggered from inside the VM itself through Windows Task Scheduler via a script that calls:  *shutdown.exe /s*.  There's nothing manual about that.

Comment: Ah ok I got it now